# Fading element in the center of window by scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

I use a script in which elements fade in from the left and right as soon as the respective element has been scrolled completely into view. The problem is, the fade-in remains until the element has completely disappeared from the field of view. I try to implement it in such a way that it fades out as soon as it is no longer completely in sight. Otherwise, all elements are shown at the same time when scrolling.

```js
function Utils() {}
Utils.prototype = {
  constructor: Utils,
  isElementInView: function(element, fullyInView) {
    var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
    var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

    if (fullyInView === true) {
      return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
    } else {
      return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
    }
  }
};

var Utils = new Utils();
$(window).on('load', addFadeIn());

$(window).scroll(function() {
  addFadeIn(true);
});

function addFadeIn(repeat) {
  var classToFadeIn = ".will-fadeIn";

  $(classToFadeIn).each(function(index) {
    var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($(this), false);
    if (isElementInView) {
      if (!($(this).hasClass('fadeInRight')) && !($(this).hasClass('fadeInLeft'))) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) $(this).addClass('fadeInRight');
        else $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
      }
    } else if (repeat) {
      $(this).removeClass('fadeInRight');
      $(this).removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#locations-mobile {
     height: auto;
     display: block;
}
 #loc1, #loc2, #loc3, #loc4 {
     height: 300px;
     background-size: cover;
}
 .locimg {
     width: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 .loc {
     cursor: pointer;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
}
 .loc .fadedbox, .loc-selected {
     background-color: #202020;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     color: #fff;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     opacity: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .loc:hover .fadedbox, .loc-selected {
     opacity: 0.8;
}
 .loc .text, .loc .text a, .will-fadeIn .text, .will-fadeIn .text p, .will-fadeIn .text p a {
     top: 0%;
     left: 0%;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transform: translateY(50px);
     -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
}
 .loc .text, .loc .text a, .will-fadeIn .text, .will-fadeIn .text p, .will-fadeIn .text p a {
     transform: translateY(30px);
     -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
}
 .loc .title {
     font-size: 2.5em;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     opacity: 0;
     transition-delay: 0.2s;
     transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
 .will-fadeIn .text .title a {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 2.5em;
}
 #loc1 {
     grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 #loc2 {
     grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 #loc3 {
     grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 #loc4 {
     grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 .doing {
     transform: rotate(-35deg);
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -90px;
     margin-top: 25px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 300px;
     color: #fff;
}
 .will-fadeIn {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 640px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #202020;
}
 .fadeInRight {
     -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     -moz-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     -ms-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     -o-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
}
 @media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
     .fadeInRight .animated {
         -webkit-animation: unset !important;
         animation: unset !important;
         -webkit-transition: none !important;
         transition: none !important;
    }
}
 .fadeInLeft {
     -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     -moz-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     -ms-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
}
 @media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
     .fadeInLeft .animated {
         -webkit-animation: unset !important;
         animation: unset !important;
         -webkit-transition: none !important;
         transition: none !important;
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-ms-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-o-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-ms-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-o-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="locations-mobile">
  <div id="loc1">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/1#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loc2">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/2#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loc3">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/3#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loc4">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/4#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please can you add your markup and styles? Thanks.

Comment: I hope that's what you meant @Rounin

Comment: still missing the styles?

Comment: @KendelVentonda your problem should be reproducible in a snippet so you should post your relevant code as a snippet in your question

Comment: @schellmax added the code snippet.

Comment: your example code differs from your problem description: the black overlays don't fade in as soon as the element "has been scrolled completely into view", but as soon they become partly visible. i'd be willing to fix this for you, but won't finde the time before tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Use the `deltaY` attribute in the `wheel` event to detect scrolling up vs down.

```js
window.onwheel = function(event) {
  let div = document.querySelector('div');
  let opacity = getComputedStyle(div).opacity;
  (event.deltaY <= 0) ? (div.style.opacity = +opacity-0.1) : (div.style.opacity = +opacity+0.1);
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'deltaY: ' + event.deltaY;
};
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>deltaY: 0</p>
```

To try the example above, enter the full page mode for the snippet. Otherwise it will work, but still scroll on the page causing a not ideal effect. Scroll up for a higher opacity and scroll down for a lower opacity.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fit my problem, as the div depends on whether it's fully visible or not. And that cannot be determined with the scroll wheel alone.
I should have posted all the code before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Animate On Scroll Library](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

Its easy to use and its more efficient, hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code, will need some major cleanup but it demonstrates the solution: (i've changed the #loc containers height to 150px to make my solution reproducable in the small 'run code' preview here)

```js
function Utils() {}
Utils.prototype = {
  constructor: Utils,
  isElementInView: function(element, fullyInView) {
    var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
    var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();
    
    
    

    if (fullyInView === true) {
      return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
    } else {
      return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
    }
  }
};

var Utils = new Utils();
$(window).on('load', addFadeIn());

$(window).scroll(function() {
  addFadeIn(true);
});

function addFadeIn(repeat) {
  var classToFadeIn = ".will-fadeIn";

  $(classToFadeIn).each(function(index) {
    var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($(this), true);
    if (isElementInView) {
      if (!($(this).hasClass('fadeInRight')) && !($(this).hasClass('fadeInLeft'))) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) $(this).addClass('fadeInRight');
        else $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
      }
    } else if (repeat) {
      $(this).removeClass('fadeInRight');
      $(this).removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#locations-mobile {
     height: auto;
     display: block;
}
 #loc1, #loc2, #loc3, #loc4 {
     height: 150px;
     background-size: cover;     
}
 .locimg {
     width: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 .loc {
     cursor: pointer;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
}
.fadedbox{
  transition:all 1s;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
}
#locations-mobile>div:nth-child(even)>.fadedbox{
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
 .loc .fadedbox, .loc-selected {
     background-color: #202020;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     color: #fff;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     opacity: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .loc:hover .fadedbox, .loc-selected {
     opacity: 0.8;
}
 .loc .text, .loc .text a, .will-fadeIn .text, .will-fadeIn .text p, .will-fadeIn .text p a {
     top: 0%;
     left: 0%;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
     transform: translateY(50px);
     -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
}
 .loc .text, .loc .text a, .will-fadeIn .text, .will-fadeIn .text p, .will-fadeIn .text p a {
     transform: translateY(30px);
     -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
}
 .loc .title {
     font-size: 2.5em;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     opacity: 0;
     transition-delay: 0.2s;
     transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
 .will-fadeIn .text .title a {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 2.5em;
}
 #loc1 {
     grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 #loc2 {
     grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 #loc3 {
     grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 #loc4 {
     grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
     background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) 
}
 .doing {
     transform: rotate(-35deg);
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -90px;
     margin-top: 25px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 300px;
     color: #fff;
}
 .will-fadeIn {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 640px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #202020;
}
 .old_fadeInRight {
     -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     -moz-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     -ms-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     -o-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
     animation: fadeInRight .5s ease .4s both;
}
.fadeInRight{
  transform:translateX(0) !important;
}
 @media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
     .fadeInRight .animated {
         -webkit-animation: unset !important;
         animation: unset !important;
         -webkit-transition: none !important;
         transition: none !important;
    }
}
 .old_fadeInLeft {
     -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     -moz-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     -ms-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
     animation: fadeInLeft .5s ease .4s both;
}
.fadeInLeft{
  transform:translateX(0) !important;
}
 @media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
     .fadeInLeft .animated {
         -webkit-animation: unset !important;
         animation: unset !important;
         -webkit-transition: none !important;
         transition: none !important;
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-ms-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-o-keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes fadeInRight {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-ms-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @-o-keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes fadeInLeft {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
     to {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="locations-mobile">
  <div id="loc1">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/1#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loc2">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/2#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loc3">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/3#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loc4">
    <div class="fadedbox will-fadeIn">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="title"><a href="/standorte/4#">#</a></p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>#<br /> #
          </a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>#</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Most relevant change is switching from css *animations* to css *transitions*, making it easier to fade elements in once the are fully in view, and out once they leave.

Come back to me in case you need further explanation here.